# Fortnite for iOS reports insufficient space on my iPhone

Tags: iphone, storage

I just downloaded Fortnite for iOS and it needs 3.017 GB. I have 16GB but it still says I don’t have enough space? It says I only have 2.435 GB space.

[image]

I have deleted every app on my iPhone and it still says the same thing.

How do I get around this issue?

Answer (score 3):

You can check the available space on your iPhone by going to Settings app → General → iPhone Storage and checking for available space.

You can also check the storage usage on per app basis and delete apps or app data appropriately.